# Not able to use Json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, coffeescript

So I am trying to start using Angular services to fetch the data for me.

Currently I have this service to get a medium from my rails server:

```
angular.module('Test').factory 'MediaShow', ($resource, $http, $routeParams) ->
    class Comments
        constructor: (errorHandler) ->
            @service = $resource('/media/:id.json',
                {id: $routeParams.id},
                {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }}
            )
            @errorHandler = errorHandler

            defaults = $http.defaults.headers
            defaults.patch = defaults.patch || {}
            defaults.patch['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

        create: (attributes, successHandle) ->
            new @service
            new @service(list: attributes).$save ((list) -> successHandler(list)), @errorHandler

        all: ->
            @service.query((-> null), @errorHandler)
```

And here I attempt to use the `all()`  function in one of my controllers:

```
$scope.init = ->
        @mediumService = new MediaShow(serverErrorHandler)
        requestedData = @mediumService.all()
        $scope.medium = requestedData.medium
        console.log($scope.medium)
        keys = []
        for key of requestedData
            keys.push key
        console.log(keys)
```

And here is how it all looks in my console:

[image: jsonProblem]

So as you can see, the medium object does exist in the data that I fetched from the server. But for some reason I am not able to access it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI: `keys = []; for key of requestedData;....` this is terribly unidiomatic. It should be `keys = (key for key of requestedData)`

Comment: Or better: `keys = Object.keys(requestedData)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `medium` doesn't appear in your output, because it *doesn't exist* at the point you generate that output. The property `medium` will appear at some point *after* your console log, when the AJAX request actually completes.

The property *does* exist in the console's object explorer, because that is updated dynamically as the object changes. It will always show the current state of the object.

I know absolutely nothing about Angular, but your `all` method seems to be returning a promise. You almost certainly need to wait for that promise to complete, and *then* access the data in `medium`.

Something like:

```
scope.init = ->
    @mediumService = new MediaShow(serverErrorHandler)
    requestedData = @mediumService.all()
    requestedData.done (data) =>
      $scope.medium = data.medium
      console.log($scope.medium)
      keys = []
      for key of requestedData
          keys.push key
      console.log(keys)
```

Comment: The .done function has to be defined somewhere also? It's not built in?

Comment: Thanks! Found a way to make it wait for the data! Will accept your answer.

Comment: Inspect `$promise`, it should have a `done` function for adding callbacks.

Comment: Turned out to be `.success`